# Switching text content on click. For some reason it takes 2 clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I am attempting to change the text in a `<h1>` element via jquery.
I am pretty close! For some reason it is taking 2 clicks to toggle the text.
Any idea how I can fix this?

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/99th1w75/1/)**

**HTML**

```html
<center> 
<div class="contentTab"> 
<div class="triangle-up"></div>
<h1>CLOSE TOP HEADER</h1>
</div>
</center>
```

**CSS**

```css
.contentTab{
    width:300px;
    height:49px;
    background:#f1efef;
    border-top-right-radius:12px;
    border-top-left-radius:12px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:50%;
    left:-150px;
    margin-top:23px;
    cursor:pointer;
        }
.contentTab h1{
    color:#a9a9a9;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fcfcfc;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-weight:bold;
        }

.triangle-up {
    width: 7px;
    height: 0;    
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top:8px;
    }
.triangle-up:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #b0b0b0;
    }

.triangle-down {
    width: 7px;
    height: 0;    
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top:8px;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    }
.triangle-down:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #b0b0b0;
    }

.contentTab:hover h1, .contentTab:hover .triangle-up:after{
    color:#919191;
    border-bottom-color:#919191;
        }

.contentTab:hover {
    margin-top:18px;
    height:54px;
        }

.contentTab h1, .contentTab:hover h1, .contentTab:hover .triangle-up:after, .contentTab:hover, .triangle-down:after, .triangle-down, .contentTab {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

**JS**

```js
  $('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
  $('.contentTab ').toggleClass("contentTabActive");
  $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");
  $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
  $(".triangle-up:not(.triangle-down)").insertBefore(".contentTab h1");
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".contentTab").click(function () { $(".contentTab h1").text(function(i, v){
   return v === 'CLOSE TOP HEADER' ? 'OPEN TOP HEADER' : 'CLOSE TOP HEADER' }) });
});
```

Comment: It's because you're adding a new event listener inside of the initial `click` event listener each time the element is clicked... remove the nested event listener and it works -> https://jsfiddle.net/v4qu0gjz/

Comment: Pefect thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, your JS code should avoid nested `click` event initialization. I suppose you try to do something like that.

js

```
 $('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
  $('.contentTab ').toggleClass("contentTabActive");
  $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");
  $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
  $(".triangle-up:not(.triangle-down)").insertBefore(".contentTab h1");
  var h1 =  $(this).find("h1");
  var str =h1.text() === 'CLOSE TOP HEADER' ? 
               'OPEN TOP HEADER' : 
               'CLOSE TOP HEADER'
    h1.text(str);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your text isn't being changed on first click because **you defined the function to change that text in an event listener nested to another one**. That means there is no event listener to toggle your text when first click is made. Indeed **that event listener (to toggle text) is defined after the first click** and that's why you need two clicks to toggle your text.

Thus your code will work by just removing that nested event listener and defining your function inside the first `onclick`.

```
$('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
  $('.contentTab ').toggleClass("contentTabActive");
  $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");
  $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
  $(".triangle-up:not(.triangle-down)").insertBefore(".contentTab h1");
  $(".contentTab h1").text( function(i, v) {
    return v === 'CLOSE TOP HEADER' ? 'OPEN TOP HEADER' : 'CLOSE TOP HEADER'
  });

e.preventDefault();
```

});

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99th1w75/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the inner click function from the already click function:

```js
  $('.contentTab').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.mainContent').toggleClass("closeHeader");
  $('.contentTab ').toggleClass("contentTabActive");
  $('.triangle-up').toggleClass("triangle-down");
  $(".triangle-down").insertAfter(".contentTab h1");
  $(".triangle-up:not(.triangle-down)").insertBefore(".contentTab h1");
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".contentTab h1").text(function(i, v){
   return v === 'CLOSE TOP HEADER' ? 'OPEN TOP HEADER' : 'CLOSE TOP HEADER' });
});
```

```css
.contentTab{
 width:300px;
 height:49px;
 background:#f1efef;
 border-top-right-radius:12px;
 border-top-left-radius:12px;
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:50%;
 left:-150px;
 margin-top:23px;
 cursor:pointer;
  }
.contentTab h1{
 color:#a9a9a9;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px #fcfcfc;
 font-size:12px;
 margin-top:3px;
 font-weight:bold;
  }

.triangle-up {
    width: 7px;
    height: 0;    
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin-top:8px;
 }
.triangle-up:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #b0b0b0;
 }
 
.triangle-down {
    width: 7px;
    height: 0;    
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin-top:8px;
 -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: flipv; /*IE*/
 }
.triangle-down:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid #b0b0b0;
 }

.contentTab:hover h1, .contentTab:hover .triangle-up:after{
 color:#919191;
 border-bottom-color:#919191;
  }
 
.contentTab:hover {
 margin-top:18px;
 height:54px;
  }
  
.contentTab h1, .contentTab:hover h1, .contentTab:hover .triangle-up:after, .contentTab:hover, .triangle-down:after, .triangle-down, .contentTab {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center> 
<div class="contentTab"> 
<div class="triangle-up"></div>
<h1>CLOSE TOP HEADER</h1>
</div>
</center>
```